# PHP header redirection issue: Not going where it should

Tags: php, internet-explorer, redirect

I have an admin page in an app I've developed which allows users who are logged in as a site admin to click a link to automatically log in as a specific user (bypassing password entry).

Once the app has set the necessary session variables to log in as the chosen user, there's a block of code that looks like this:

```
if ($login->loginAsUser($_POST['selecteduser']) === TRUE) {
    //redirect to user page
    error_log ("REDIRECT TO user.php");
    //die("breakpoint 1");
    header("Location: user.php");
    exit;
} else {
    die("login error");
}
```

(it's OK - I'm validating the POST variable before this).

$login->loginAsUser(ID) is a method of my login class. It basically just destroys the current session and then creates a new one for the user login, and returns TRUE if everything was OK.

As you can see, I've added some code to write a message to the Apache error log just before the redirect. This message appears correctly in the log every time the code runs. 
But about 90% of the time what actually happens is a redirect to index.php, not to user.php. Also, this mis-redirection only seems to occur in Internet Explorer (version 11 and previous versions), and only happens about 90% of the time. Once in a while, it will redirect to the correct page.

What's even weirder is that if I uncomment the line `die("breakpoint 1");`, the browser STILL redirects to index.php, rather than halting and displaying a message.

I've tried using an absolute path for the redirect, but that doesn't improve anything.

Comment: My guess is you have a redirection elsewhere in your code being triggered by mistake.

Comment: `But about 90% of the time what actually happens is a redirect to index.php, not to user.php` is that actually "90% of the time user.php re-redirects to index.php" (you should check)? You'll need to check in your codebase where redirects to index.php are made (there are none in the question) and why.

Comment: `this mis-redirection only seems to occur in Internet Explorer` the absolute classic reason for that is because there is something loaded that is ie specific `<!--[if IE]><script src="ie.js"><!--[if IE]>` which doesn't exist, reaches your php application code and one way or another destroys the session.

Comment: Nope. There is no redirection to user.php, except on the rare occasions when it randomly seems to work correctly. The page never loads (I attempt to write to the log as the first line of user.php, but there's no sign of it in the log. And user.php is otherwise just an HTML page saying "You are here" at the moment.

Comment: then your problem is not as described.

Comment: I recommend the IE dev tools (F12). Look in the network tab at exactly what IE is seeing, and what headers it's receiving.

Comment: Now there's something... the redirect works perfectly every time when I have the IE dev tools active. Close the tool window, and it goes back to misbehaving...

Comment: Also, I have no <!--[if IE]> or similar conditions.